# Toshiba Satellite P505-S8950 - upgrade CPU?

Tags: upgrade, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba Satellite P505-S8950 which has an Intel Core 2 Duo P8700 / 2.53 GHz CPU and would like to upgrade the CPU.

I have searched Google but have been unable to determine if this is possible.

Would anyone happen to know and if so what the relative difficulty would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible upgrade would be to a [P8800](http://starmicroinc.net/intel-core-mobile-processor-p8800-266ghz-1066mhz-p-1213.html), which would at best get you about a 7% performance improvement.

Comment: That 7% difference isn't worth the cost and likely trouble that the replacement would entail. Thank you for the info David.